# Cannot move the window displayed with imshow

Tags: python, opencv

I'm not sure if there's an easy workaround for this problem, but if I create a window to display an image:

```
cv2.namedWindow('Window', cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE)
cv2.imshow('Window',self.frame)
cv2.waitKey(30)
```

it's impossible to move that window - it just freezes immediately (the application hangs). It works fine if I use `cv2.waitKey(0)`, but this code waits for keyboard input infinitely and is simply stuck at this command, invoking the infinite loop - not what I need as you may imagine.

Comment: It's basically the same as waitKey(30), it just tells to wait 1 milisecond (or 30 ms, respectively). Yes - I've tried that - didn't work. I can't move the window, dragging the mouse has no effect on its position, after I try several times the top bar displays the usual message (Program is not responding, etc.)

Comment: then, your setup (not the python code) is somehow buggy.

Comment: I'm acquiring the image from my webcam and I display it in an infinite loop using imshow. Is there any way to exit the loop once I close the window with mouse? Cause now after I close it it just pops up again - I'd like to exit that loop, close the window without using keyboard.

Comment: `if cv2.waitKey(1)&0xff == 27: break `  - no, closing the window with mouse won't help. imshow() will create a new window if nessecary.

Answer (score 0):

May be you are using a large image for the operation which causes it to stop try using:

```
cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) # access webcam
_, frame = cap.read()

cv2.namedWindow("image", cv2.WINDOW_NORMAL)

cv2.imshow("image", img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This takes the first image that the webcam sees and displays it.Now whenever you press a key the image window will close.